# Vba apply conditional formatting top/bottom border only?

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I am using the following vba code to apply conditional formatting.

```
Sub ResetConditions()
    With Worksheets(1).Range("A9:P1048576")
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
          "=ROW(B9)=ROW(OFFSET($B$9,COUNTA($B:$B)-2,0))"
        With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)
            .SetFirstPriority

            With .Borders
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlThin
            .Color = vbRed
            End With

        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

The border is showing as this:

[image]

But i want it to look like this:

[image]

I am trying to set only top/bottom borders like so:

```
Sub ResetConditions()
        With Worksheets(1).Range("A9:P1048576")
            .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
              "=ROW(B9)=ROW(OFFSET($B$9,COUNTA($B:$B)-2,0))"
            With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)
                .SetFirstPriority

                With .Borders(xlEdgeTop)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Weight = xlThin
                .Color = vbRed
                End With

            End With
        End With
    End Sub
```

But i keep getting an error unable to set linestyle property of border class.

Please can someone show me where i am going wrong?

Comment: Try recording a macro while setting conditional formatting using top border format. You will see, that `Excel` itself will using `.Borders(xlTop)` instead of `.Borders(xlEdgeTop)`. So probably [Borders Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837809.aspx) for ranges differs from `Borders` collection from  [FormatCondition.Borders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196030.aspx) in this not documented way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this...

```
Sub ResetConditions()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim n As Integer
    Set ws = Sheets(1)
    Set Rng = ws.Range("A9:P1048576")

    Rng.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=ROW(B9)=ROW(OFFSET($B$9,COUNTA($B:$B)-2,0))"
    n = Rng.FormatConditions.Count
    Rng.FormatConditions(n).SetFirstPriority
    With Rng.FormatConditions(n).Borders(xlTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlThin
        .Color = vbRed
    End With
    With Rng.FormatConditions(n).Borders(xlBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlThin
        .Color = vbRed
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use for border ranges:

```
Public Sub BorderMe(my_range)

    Dim l_counter   As Long

    For l_counter = 7 To 10 '7 to 10 are the magic numbers for xlEdgeLeft etc
        With my_range.Borders(l_counter)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlMedium
        End With
    Next l_counter

End Sub
```

You may edit the color, the weight, style and etc.
The magic ist that 7,8,9 and 10 are the numbers of Excel for `xlEdgeLeft`, `xlEdgeRight`, `xlEdgeTop` and `xlEdgeBottom`.

Run it like this:`call borderme(selection)` in the immediate window, to see what is does.

Answer (score 0):

```
   Rng.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, _
    Formula1:="=10"
Rng.FormatConditions(Rng.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Rng.FormatConditions(Rng.FormatConditions.Count).Borders(xlTop)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
    .Color = vbRed
End With
With Rng.FormatConditions(Rng.FormatConditions.Count).Borders(xlBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
    .Color = vbRed
End With
```

Try this code dont forget to set rng Set Rng = Range("")